# Multiple field comparison with IF/OR Staement in word mailmerge

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, mailmerge

I am preparing a mailmerge that displays a text "Everything is included" if atleast one of the field values is "yes",  but does not Display anything if all of the field values is "No"

My code is currently  `{IF{MERGEFIELD field1}="yes" OR{MERGEFIELD field2}="yes" OR {MERGEFIELD field3}="yes" OR {MERGEFIELD field3}="yes" OR {MERGEFIELD field4}="yes"} "Everything is included" ""}`

But I keep getting error of conditional OP

Comment: Why is field3 referenced twice?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from my research, AND and OR are not valid in Word merge fields https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MailMerge/MMergeIfFields.htm. Emulate this logic with nested IF.

```
{IF {MERGEFIELD field1} = "yes" "Everything is included" 
   {IF {MERGEFIELD field2} = "yes" "Everything is included" 
      {IF {MERGEFIELD field3} = "yes" "Everything is included" 
         {IF {MERGEFIELD field4} = "yes" "Everything is included" ""}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are 5 fields, use:

```
{IF{MERGEFIELD field1}= "yes" {IF{MERGEFIELD field2}= "yes" {IF{MERGEFIELD field3}= "yes" {IF{MERGEFIELD field4}= "yes" {IF{MERGEFIELD field5}= "yes" "Everything is included"}}}}}
```

or:

```
{IF«field1»= "yes" {IF«field2»= "yes" {IF«field3»= "yes" {IF«field4»= "yes" {IF«field5»= "yes" "Everything is included"}}}}}
```

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. Likewise, the chevrons (i.e. '« »') are part of the actual mergefields - which you can insert from the 'Insert Merge Field' dropdown (i.e. you can't type or copy & paste them from this message, either). The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required.

Answer (score 0):

The OR function can only test numeric values.

Assuming there are 5 fields, use:

```
{IF{={IF{MERGEFIELD field1}= "yes" 1 0}+{IF{MERGEFIELD field2}= "yes" 1 0}+{IF{MERGEFIELD field3}= "yes" 1 0}+{IF{MERGEFIELD field4}= "yes" "yes" 1 0}+{IF{MERGEFIELD field5}= "yes" "yes" 1 0}}> 0 "Everything is included"}
```

or:

```
{IF{={IF«field1»= "yes" 1 0}+{IF«field2»= "yes" 1 0}+{IF«field3»= "yes" 1 0}+{IF«field4»= "yes" "yes" 1 0}+{IF«field5»= "yes" "yes" 1 0}}> 0 "Everything is included"}
```

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. Likewise, the chevrons (i.e. '« »') are part of the actual mergefields - which you can insert from the 'Insert Merge Field' dropdown (i.e. you can't type or copy & paste them from this message, either). The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required.